# Root HTC one V on Mac OS X

Tags: rooting, macos, htc-one-v, z4root

I'd like to root my HTC One V. Are there any tools specifically for this?

I'm trying to follow this [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1869667) but having trouble with step 6 in the HTCdev-Unlock Bootloader guide.

Currently, running Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: AndroidForums has a guide for [rooting the HTC One V](http://androidforums.com/one-v-all-things-root/520198-htc-one-v-all-things-root-%20guide-updated-7-nov-2012-a.html). *I can't post the steps here, since the link is blocked at my current location.*

Comment: That guide states, "If you run Mac, I can’t help you." I'm looking for something specific to Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this guide: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1869667 but having trouble with step 6 in the HTCdev-Unlock Bootloader guide.

Comment: I took the freedom to add your question to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575), where we link one question per device (so future visitors looking for how-to-root-One-V should come here). You might want to check there, maybe a solution for a related device susch as the *One X* or *One XL* could work for you?

Comment: HTC has a tool called HTC Quick Root tool it works with the latest crop of HTC’s Android devices, including the One X, One S and One V. As far as i'm aware it is available for PC only http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1870652

Comment: http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/unlock-instructions/page-2 does have some instruction regarding Mac OS X, for example, step 5 states "Note: for Mac OS X and Linux you will only need adb and fastboot." and even includes a link to fasboot for mac http://www.htcdev.com/process/legal_fastboot_mac, but after that, it shows windows command prompt steps only.

Comment: @AndrewOgryzek Have a look at this article to see if it helps at all  http://www.bestandroidblog.com/how-to-unlock-the-bootloader-in-htc-one-v/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't root your phone because your on Mac OS X, try running a virtual machine that is running windows and root your phone from there. (I Personally don't have a Mac so am not 100% sure this will work, this is only a suggestion)

Comment: Matt07211 - That would probably make a better comment than answer, as it would still require purchasing and running Windows OS - Bootcamp would would also work, if that were a solution. Anyway, I've had 2 phone upgrades since posting that 2 and a half years ago!

Comment: My fault for not checking the date it was posted, sorry and at the time I was unable to comment as I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

There are some Apps to root most of the Phones for example KingRoot is a good one
https://kingroot.net/ install that on your phone and you can easily root